# Laravel 5 checkbox not storing value from submit form

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have added a checkbox to my existing submit form that must change from value 0 to 1 if it is activated. But they dont' save the value, it's always 0.

My code:

```
 <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="true" name="trackingnumber"> You provide an Tracking Number   
 </label>
```

ProductController:

```
if ($request->trackingnumber == 'true') {
    $product->trackingnumber = true;
}
```

What have I forgotten?

Comment: Can you show more code? Do you run `$product->save()` somewhere to save it into database?

Comment: What’s the content of `$request->trackingnumber`? Have you tried looking at it with `dd($request->trackingnumber);` for example?

Comment: Why don't you show us the contents of the request?

Comment: What you mean with contents of the request?

Answer (score 1):

Okay i have just change the `id="inlineCheckbox1"` and works now

Answer (score 0):

In your ProductController do

`if ($request->trackingnumber == 'on') {`

and set the value also to "on" in your html
and it should work

or you just simply `dd($request)`

Comment: No change, the same... always 0 value

Answer (score 0):

in this situation try dd($request) in your controller and check what it contain in that.

**Update:**

Hey please put checkbox value="1" and then check what value of checkbox is there in request.

Comment: please can you share what output you get

Comment: and try this dd(Request()) instead of dd($request)

Comment: I dont get any output, all other submitted values are saved in DB but "trackingnumber" are always  "0"

Comment: on the starting of your function you have to write like this public function index(){ dd(Request()); } and check what value it contain